# Run random test cases on TFS

Tags: asp.net, selenium, tfs, automation, nunit

I have schedule regression automation that is running everyday from TFS, I want to develop functionality to run only failed test case against latest build not whole regression automation again.

Is there a way, I can only call web api and pass only failed test case name and when I trigger deploy to any environment that will only run

Or is there any other way around this.

Comment: TFS has recently introduced "Run Impacted Tests". This will run tests for which the Code Coverage data has changed and tests that have recently failed or have been unstable.

Comment: TFS 2017.1 and later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/test-impact-analysis?view=vsts

Comment: @jessehouwing I want to run failed test case again. Not only Impacted Tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a `Rerun failed tests` option in [the v2.* of the VSTest task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) in the build definition, you could select this option to rerun the failed tests:

[image]

If you want to use api, you would need to follow the steps below:

1. [Get test results for a test run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/list) and find out the failed test cases.

`GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5`

2. [Create a new test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20%20suites/create) by querying the failed test case IDs:

`POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}?api-version=5.0-preview.3`

`Content-Type:application/json`

`{
  "suiteType": "DynamicTestSuite",
  "name": "FailedTestCases",
  "queryString": "SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType],[System.Title],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority],[System.AssignedTo],[System.AreaPath] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP 'Microsoft.TestCaseCategory' AND ( [System.Id] = xxx OR [System.Id] = xxx )"
}`

3. Select Test Plan and Test suite in your VSTest task:

[image]

Comment: I am running automation test case using DLL, I don't have any test case in TFS, How I will fetch Test case Ids and Create Test Plan ??

Comment: Since you don't have test cases in TFS, how do you want to use TFS to run automatic tests? In my step 1, it will return the test cases IDs, and regarding how to create test plan, you could refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/getting-started/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts